# How to Retrive multiple sequences from a database in Bioperl?

Tags: perl, bioperl

I have installed Bioperl1.6 via ppm and have placed .pl file in cgi-bin folder of my localhost. When I run this via url 
http://localhost/cgi-bin/bio2.pl 
it says "Internal Server Error"

While if run any of the bioperl file either in CGI or .pl it complain same as Internal server error.

```
 #!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe

use Bio::SeqIO;
use Bio::DB::GenBank;
use Bio::DB::Query::GenBank;

$query = "Arabidopsis[ORGN] AND topoisomerase[TITL] and 0:3000[SLEN]";
$query_obj = Bio::DB::Query::GenBank->new(-db    => 'nucleotide',  -query => $query );

$gb_obj = Bio::DB::GenBank->new;

$stream_obj = $gb_obj->get_Stream_by_query($query_obj);

while ($seq_obj = $stream_obj->next_seq) {    
    # do something with the sequence object    
    print $seq_obj->display_id, "\t", $seq_obj->length, "\n";
}
```

if I run this code via cmd then it says genebank cant be found excptn.

Please guide me how to run bioperl in perl cgi.